# Chrome Extension: html parsing creating object instead of source code (manifest v3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to migrate an existing chrome extension into a manifest v3 extension and I keep on bumping into issues. I have managed to address most of them but I now have another case where I have no clue on what is happening.

The goal of the extension is to read the source code of a page and parse the HTML.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript( 
    {
        target: {tabId: tab.id, allFrames: true},
        files: ['GetSource.js'],
    }, async function(results) 
    {
        console.log(results);
        parser = new DOMParser();
        content = parser.parseFromString(results, "text/html");
        console.log(content);   
...etc...
```

The content of "results" is the source code as expected, at that stage everything is ok. When I display the content of "content", I get this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>[object Object]</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I get an object instead of the code. I'm using the same code in the v2 and it works.

The code is executed in popup.js not in background.js

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Use devtools to debug your code and you'll see that `results` is an array of objects with a property `result` so you should parse each one individually, [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#handling-results).

Comment: @wOxxOm you're completely right (again). Thanks for pointing out but do you know why the same code was running without any issue in v2 and led me to this issue in v3?

Comment: Because chrome.scripting is a different API.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer, I will select it as the right answer for this post. Thanks for your help!